# How to type an exported RelayContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, relayjs

I'm trying to type (with flowtype) the components I'm enhancing with `Relay.createContainer`.

I looked into the [types exported](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/RelayTypes.js) by the "react-relay" package but [ReactContainer](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/RelayTypes.js#L86) doesn't seem to carry over Props.

I experimented with `RelayContainer`, `ReactClass`, `React$Component` etc,
in the end the closest thing to the expected result I could get is :

```
// Foo.js
// @flow
import React from "react";
import Relay from "react-relay";

type Props = { title: string; }
const Foo({ title }: Props) => (<div>{title}</div>);

const exported: Class<React$Component<void, Props, void>> = Relay.createContainer(Foo, {
  fragments: { ... }
});

export default exported;
```

--

```
// Bar.js
// @flow

import React from "react";
import Foo from "./Foo.js";
const Bar = () => <Foo />;
```

Now flow will complain in `Foo.js` around Props that Bar doesn't provide the title prop, which kinda what I want (I'd like it to complain in `Bar.js` but it's a detail).
However if Bar was also a `RelayContainer` referencing Foo's fragment flow would complain that it can't find `getFragment` in Foo's properties:

```
// Bar.js
// @flow

import React from "react";
import Relay from "react-relay";
import Foo from "./Foo.js";

const Bar = () => <Foo />; 

export default Relay.createContainer(Bar, {
  fragments: {
    baz: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Baz {
        ${Foo.getFragment("foo")}
      }
    `
  }
}
```

In the end I'm trying to type the output of `Relay.createContainer` so that it carries over the typing of the decorated component. I looked into the Relay's internal types and saw `https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/8567b2732d94d75f0eacdce4cc43c3606960a1d9/src/query/RelayFragmentReference.js#L211` but I feel like it's not the way to go to add in Relay's properties.

Any idea how could I achieve this ?

Comment: related https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1155

Comment: The outline above seems promising. I'm going to see if I can augment it to tell Flow that the higher order component adds a static getFragment method. If anyone has come up with a better alternative, it would be nice to learn!

Comment: Lee Byron announced yesterday at react-europe that Relay 1.0.0 will generate __generated__/* files for each fragment and that they will export flowtypes. so I guess this will solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @gre pointed out, now the Relay Compiler generates Flow types for the fragment and these are exported in generated files within a `__generated__` subdirectory.

generating said file by running the Relay Compiler

`relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.json`

You would then import the flow types for the field props like so:

```
import type { MyComponent_myField } from "./__generated__/MyComponent_myField.graphql";
class MyComponent extends Component<{
  myField: MyComponent_myField,
}> {
  render() {
    return <div>Example</div>;
  }
}
export default createFragmentContainer(MyComponent, {
  myField: graphql`
    fragment MyComponent_myField on MyType {
       edges {
          node {
            _id
            foo
          }
       }
    }
  `
});
```

Although AFAIK currently types for spreaded fragments are not generated [unless you use the Haste module system](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2316#issuecomment-364040783)